# Processes in uninterruptable sleep killing server

Tags: linux, opensuse, performance

I have a opensuse 11 64 bit server with some issues I'm not sure how to solve. I'm getting hundreds of these in the porocess list:

```
4     0  3105     1  20   0  55420  3488 646312 Sl   ?          0:02 /usr/lib/udisks/udisks-daemon
1     0  3106  3105  20   0  46700   800 685268 S    ?          0:25  \_ udisks-daemon: polling /dev/sr0
4     0 21303  3105  20   0  13296   728 -      D    ?          0:00  \_ udisks-helper-ata-smart-collect /dev/sdb 1
0     0 21847  3105  20   0  13296   436 scsi_b D    ?          0:00  \_ udisks-helper-ata-smart-collect /dev/sdb 1
0     0 22399  3105  20   0  13296   440 -      D    ?          0:00  \_ udisks-helper-ata-smart-collect /dev/sdb 1
0     0 22935  3105  20   0  13296   436 -      D    ?          0:00  \_ udisks-helper-ata-smart-collect /dev/sdb 1
0     0 23474  3105  20   0  13296   440 -      D    ?          0:00  \_ udisks-helper-ata-smart-collect /dev/sdb 1
0     0 24023  3105  20   0  13296   440 -      D    ?          0:00  \_ udisks-helper-ata-smart-collect /dev/sdb 1
0     0 24559  3105  20   0  13296   436 -      D    ?          0:00  \_ udisks-helper-ata-smart-collect /dev/sdb 1
0     0 25100  3105  20   0  13296   436 -      D    ?          0:00  \_ udisks-helper-ata-smart-collect /dev/sdb 1
0     0 25639  3105  20   0  13296   440 -      D    ?          0:00  \_ udisks-helper-ata-smart-collect /dev/sdb 1
```

Generally over 300 or so over a couple of days, the load averages can get as high as 300 or so BUT the server is still responsive ~ I suspect the load averages are being reported incorrectly for some reason.  I know the only way to get rid of these processes is to reboot, but I'm trying to figure out how to prevent them from appearing. I've disabled the smartd daemon, I've unmounted the /dev/sdb partition. I don't know what's calling the udisk helper...

any thoughts on how to track this down and prevent it from happening?

[BTW - I have tested the disk manually, it is fine - not failing.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug.  See the following thread:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1573929&page=2

Comment: The workaround does seem to work. [would be nice of there was an actual fix though]

Answer (score 0):

Usualy this is a problem related a hardware resource that the process is trying to access, maybe can be a driver/module related to the disk controller or its firmware version. Try to check some bugs/issues are reported for your hw

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot add anything to your main problem, I would like to note that the load average is not, in fact, incorrect. Load is defined as the average number of processes waiting for resources (not necessarily CPU), and each process in "D" state counts as one toward the machine's load.